# ICU regex quoting

Tags: c++, icu

I am wondering if there is a way to quote a string in the ICU (c++) library. There exists "\Q" + string + "\E" but I am having generated input come in as the string provided. There does not seem to be any ICU quote regex method. Would just changing all "\E" in string to \\E work.

Comment: Another option that might work is to convert all characters of "string" into \x{hhhh} format, but that doesn't seem ideal...

Answer (score 1):

I'd file a feature request with your use case. I don't think there's currently a function to do this.